# Allow only specific multiple emails to register in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, email-validation

I'm trying to do a verification system for web app in rails which only allows people with certain email addresses to register.

I've seen couple of articles on stackoverflow about this but they mostly discuss about only one email domain, and in my case I need more of them.

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@domain1\.com\z/, message: "must be a domain1.com account" }
```

I've tried adding this line of code in my **user.rb** file in models and tried to add all kinds of variations to it in order to have more cases accepted but I always end up with following:

1.Everything get's accepted( domains I want and those I don't want)

2.Nothing get's accepted

3.Only last one get's accepted

4.Only first one gets accepted

I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Do add some examples of domains you accept and those you do not accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(domain1|domain2)\.com\z
```